# java.util.zip.ZipInputStream nulls partway through decompress

Tags: java, android, zip

zipped xml string which has been retrieved from a web response given by production server.
String is good as same methodology in .net gives valid result. (The data is a list of car makes.)
In Android however the ZipInputStream read produces a buffer of the right size (4895) but it has null data from position 2661 onwards.  The last car decompressed correctly is 'MG'

The method does not error.

Can anybody see what is wrong?
thanks

```
private byte[] decompressZip(String zipText) throws IOException{


    try {
        byte[] zipBytes = MakeBytes(zipText);
        byte[] zipData;
        ByteArrayInputStream b = new ByteArrayInputStream(zipBytes);
        BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(b);

        //ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(b); doesn't matter both constuctors have the fault.
        ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(buf);
        ZipEntry entry;
        if((entry=zin.getNextEntry())!=null)
        {
            int entrySize=(int)entry.getSize();
            zipData = new byte[entrySize];
            zin.read(zipData, 0, entrySize);

            return zipData;

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        String sError = e.getMessage();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It would interesting to see the number of bytes read from the read method. [Edit] In fact, I would look at all the sizes to be sure there's no silliness. To be clear `zipBytes.length`, `entrySize` and `int bytesRead = zin.read(zipData, 0, entrySize);`

Comment: Hi Gary,Problem solved using the buffered approach. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html